# Run java Spring project in port 8443 ( https ) in localhost

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, https, localhost

I have been trying to run my java spring project in HTTPS mode in my localhost.

The project works perfectly in HTTP but form some features, i need it to run in HTTPS

i have changed the default port to 8443 in the **server.xml** in **tomcat**. When i run the spring project, its URL shows **https://localhost:8443** instead of **localhost:8080** but the page does not load. It says page not found.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Look at your `server.xml` again.  Did you set the default port to 84**3**3 instead of 84**4**3?

Comment: i am sure that i set the port to 8443

Comment: The eason I ask is that you say you "changed the default port to 8443", but that the "URL shows https://localhost:8433".  That's two different ports; is it a typo in your question, or a real problem in your configuration?

Comment: oh.... thats mistake.. The rul is also pointing to port 8443 but when i load the javaproject, it display page not found

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a `Connector` that listens on port 8443 and a SSL certificate (`keystore` file in the example below, set the location as you see fit):

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystoreFile="${user.home}/keystore" keystorePass="tomcat" keyAlias="tomcat"/>
```

You can buy a SSL certificate or locally sign it yourself (although you’ll get a browser exception that will ask manual confirmation to accept it). To do the latter you can use Java’s `keytool`.

Comment: yes, i have set that connector on. After i load the spring project, it runs in HTTPS but get an error saying page not found

Comment: Can you access the same page over HTTP?

Comment: A very quick way to know what is failing (Tomact or your Spring webapp) is to go to Tomcat’s manager GUI over HTTPS: https://localhost:8443/manager. Does that work?

Comment: If you can access the manager over HTTP and not HTTPS it means that your Tomcat, specifically the HTTPS `<Connector>`, isn’t properly configured. That’s an internal Tomcat page unrelated to your Spring webapp.

Comment: i can neither access the Tomcat GUI localhost:8443/manager nor localhost:8080/manager . It display page not found